# How to make tuple with list of dictionary inpython?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dictionary and I want to make tuple from tags value, So that the tags in an array are placed in pairs.
How can I do this:

```
output: [
        {
          "title": "subject1",
          "tags": ['a','b'],
 },
        {
          "title": "subject2",
          "tags": ['c','d','f'],
 }]
```

what I want:

```
[(a,b),(c,d),(c,f),(d,f)]
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @bichanna Yes I wrote a code but it doesn't consider the duplicate tags

Comment: @bichanna def get_edges_from_list(l):
    edges = []
    for i,x in enumerate(l[:-1]):
        edges.append((x, l[i+1]))
    return edges

label = set(sum([get_edges_from_list(x['tags']) for x in output], []))

Comment: @z-g for future, please always include your code attempts in the question  it's hard to read them in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations(... , 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and get what you want like below:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> results = [{"title": "subject1","tags": ['a','b'],},{"title": "subject2","tags": ['c','d','f'],}]

>>> lst = [list(itertools.combinations(res['tags'] , 2)) for res in results]
>>> lst
[[('a', 'b')], [('c', 'd'), ('c', 'f'), ('d', 'f')]]

>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'f'), ('d', 'f')]
```

Or without chain:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> results = [{"title": "subject1","tags": ['a','b'],},{"title": "subject2","tags": ['c','d','f'],}]
>>> out = []
>>> for res in results:
...    out += list(itertools.combinations(res['tags'] , 2))
>>> out
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'f'), ('d', 'f')]

# for more explanation
[1,2]+[3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: How can I add itertools, pip install itertools dose not work

Comment: @z-g you had this, this is original python library, did you run code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations()` to get it. The following will work

```py
from itertools import combinations

L1 = [{"title": "subject1", "tags": ['a','b']},
      {"title": "subject2", "tags": ['c','d','f']}]

res = []

for i in L1:
    tags = combinations(i["tags"], 2)
    res += list(tags)

print(res)
```